# Can I display a python return value on a html page

Tags: python

I have developed a python script that basically authenticates and performs queries in jira. I then return my result for all three queries. What I want to do is return my result in the form of a color (red , green , yellow). Maybe a box that displays color on a html page. So Basically i'm trying to show the health in the form of a color based on my queries. First is there a way to display my python scripts return [low,med,high] on a html page ? Second can I display more of a visual representation of my queries ?
code below

```
import jira

def pull_Defect(JiraKey,ComponentType):
    jac = jira.JIRA('http://****',basic_auth=('****','*****'))
    #pid_Num_Sev = []
    #project_key = "sjdgsd"
    #issues = jira.search_issues('project = ' + project_Key)

    low = jac.search_issues('project = ' + JiraKey + ' AND "Project/Component"=' + ComponentType + ' AND Severity=Low')
    med = jac.search_issues('project = ' + JiraKey + ' AND "Project/Component"=' + ComponentType + ' AND Severity=Medium')
    high = jac.search_issues('project = ' + JiraKey + ' AND "Project/Component"=' + ComponentType + ' AND Severity=High')
    return [low,med,high]
```

Comment: Look into Python Flask.  You can make a very simple Python web API, then use an AJAX query to get the return value from Python and do something with it in your page.  It sounds like a lot, but it's very doable.

Comment: @SurrealDreams looks like we had the same thought. :)

Comment: Thank you very much....... Does it make a difference if I'm trying to display my python return on a Atlassian Confluence page ? I know I said an HTML page but its actually a confluence page which I have had alot of problems with. Will Flask still be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use Flask. It's a fantastic framework that will let you do what you are looking for and so much more. It might seem like overkill, but it's such an awesome little framework, that it will let you do more.

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Thank you very much....... Does it make a difference if I'm trying to display my python return on a Atlassian Confluence page ? I know I said an HTML page but its actually a confluence page which I have had alot of problems with. Will Flask still be helpful

Comment: It shouldn't really. I think the important thing is just making sure that you are providing the proper data as expected by the confluence API.